# How i can check if user switched iCloud account?

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit

I make sync between CoreData and iCloud(CloudKit). How i can check if user switched iCloud account?

**Other problem:**

The user uses my app with iCloud account "A". He addes data. All data will copy in CKContainer "A".
If user will switch account on iCloud account "B".  I will add current data in new CKContainer "B".

But if user return back  iCloud account "A", I need add current data from  CKContainer "B" to CKContainer "A" without duplicates. How to solve a problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an observer within your app for `Notification.Name.CKAccountChanged`, then clear local data and pull from iCloud again.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .CKAccountChanged, object: self, queue: nil) { notification in
     ...
}
```